# Why is this appearing behind the canvas instead of drawing over it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png

I am working on a dynamic web map with HTML5 and canvas.

I loaded the map in PNG format, but whenever I try to draw on it, it draws behind the map like this:

[image: Map example]

I need it to draw **over** the white squares.

This is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
  img.src = "img/plano.png"; //transparent png
  ctx.fillRect(1039, 150, 50, 50);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: onload is async

Comment: So, i need to load the image on onload and create an event to draw the shape?

Comment: Yes, move the code to draw the shape to the bottom of the onload function of the image

Comment: I have already moved it to the end of the file, but it is still putting the shape behind the picture, here is a fiddle: [fiddle] https://jsfiddle.net/46ufvobr/, but i actually think that i am doing this the wrong way, thanks in advance for any help and thanks @dougtesting.net for your answer

Comment: Hi @JoseSanchezGarcia, not the end of the file, the fillRect needs to happen after the drawImage

Comment: @dougtesting.net thanks, that worked out, i owe you one ;)

Answer (score 0):

The fillRect needs to happen after the image has loaded. The image loads asynchronously so the only safe place for this to happen is after the drawImage...

```
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillRect(200,200,50,50);  // Draw rect after image
}
```